# Cannot create new database in MySQL - logging in as 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, root

For some reason when I login into MySQL - mysql -uroot -p*****

I get this error when running this procedure -

```
mysql> create database new_database;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'new_database'
```

These are my privileges currently

```
Grants for root@localhost                                               
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `testdb`.* TO 'root'@'localhost'
```

How do I get all privileges or superuser to root@localhost

Comment: Unless this turns out to be a pi specific bug, this is a general sql question. Also need more info, distro and mysql version. I have seen different issues pop up similar with this in different versions of both.

Answer (score 2):

Try logging in like this

```
mysql -u root -p
```

You are telling it to log as the user root with a password you will provide.

It will prompt you for your password and allow you to access mysql.

That is how I access it as root and have no problem with making changes.

You can try granting all privileges on the database after creating it:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON new_database.*
TO 'root'@'localhost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'your_password';
```

Then you can show the grants for root and verify it has access:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Pretty much identical to my login - I add my password after the '-p' to speed things up.

Still get an error tho.

Comment: Edited the answer to expand on granting access.

Comment: it throws error as soon as I try to create the new_database, so granting privilge would theoretically come after creation of new db, for me anyway

Comment: when I run your above command I get - ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: found this link on Stack Overflow, might help you with granting the privileges for root. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges